# Deep merging in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment

I have the following structure:

```
database: {
 events: {}
}
```

I would like to achieve the following, or something similar.

```
database.events[eventKey]["staff"][role].push(value)
```

eventKey, role and value are variables.

Is there a way to push it to this array?

Maybe with `Object.assign()` somehow?

Comment: This is not merging. And yes its possible, however i bet there are better datastructures...

Comment: I want it to merge if the array is already existing, not overwrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight-forward but cumbersome way is to just do an existence check for each individual property before trying to access it:

```
if (
  database.events[eventKey] &&
  database.events[eventKey].staff &&
  database.events[eventKey].staff[role]
) {
  database.events[eventKey].staff[role].push(value)
}
```

*Note*: This will also check the prototype chain so you might wanna use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) in that case.

If operations like this are performed many times, creating a helper that does such property extraction might be useful:

```
const getProp = (obj, path) => {
  const props = path.split('.');
  let val = obj;
  for (let prop of props) {
    val = val[prop];
    if (val === undefined || val === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
  return val;
}
```

Which would be used like:

```
const roles = getProp(database, `events.${eventKey}.staff.${role}`)
if (Array.isArray(roles)) {
  roles.push(value);
}
```

Or maybe with a default fallback if you don't care about the truthy check edge cases:

```
(getProp(database, `events.${eventKey}.staff.${role}`) || []).push(value)
```

Using a [helper](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#property) from a well-known & well-tested utility library like lodash would also make sense in this case:

```
const getRole = _.property(`events.${eventKey}.staff.${role}`)
// ...
const role = getRole(database);
if (Array.isArray(role)) {
  role.push(value);
}
```